# SQL to LINQ Conversion having an XPath Query

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, xpath, linq-to-sql

I am beginning to remove some SQL code out of a stored procedure and convert it to LINQ to be used in my C# .NET application. Using the example below, the query should return true if the xpath finds a match in the XML column data. I am new to LINQ so converting this query has been challenging. Any help would be appreciated! \m/ \m/

```
declare
@userID       as uniqueidentifier = '8D1FA128-1684-487F-B7B2-978CE7FC6C83',
@isRockNRoll  as bit;

select @isRockNRoll = CASE WHEN EXISTS(select 1 from dbo.[MyTableName] where [myTableColumnName].query('/descendant-or-self::node()/text').value('text[1]/@userID','varchar(40)') = CONVERT(varchar(40),@userID)
                      and [myTableColumnName].query('/descendant-or-self::node()/text').value('text[1]/@genre','varchar(50)') = 'RockNRoll') THEN 1
                      ELSE 0 END

-- myTableColumnName XML column value:
-- <userID>8D1FA128-1684-487F-B7B2-978CE7FC6C83</userID><genre>RockNRoll</genre>
```

Example .NET Implementation.

```
    private bool IsRockNRoll(Guid userID)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            var strIsRockNRoll = (from TBL in context.MyTableName
                                  where TBL.myTableColumnName.userID == userID
                                  && TBL.myTableColumnName.genre == "RockNRoll").SingleOrDefault();

            if (strIsRockNRoll != null)
            {
                    return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add at least what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here is an example .NET implementation using LINQ. It is not going to work but should give you an idea of what I trying to accomplish. The column myTableColumnName datatype is XML. I do not know how to query the XML column value using LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to LINQ but this seems to work... \m/ \m/

```
private bool IsRockNRoll(Guid userID)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        bool blnIsRockNRoll = false;
        var result = (from o in context.MyTableName.AsEnumerable()
                        where o.myTableColumnName.Contains(userID.ToString())
                        && o.myTableColumnName.Contains("RockNRoll")
                        select o).ToList();

        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            blnIsRockNRoll = true;
        }

        return blnIsRockNRoll;
    }
}
```